# Get specific detail onPress marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn ReactNative

I've got a JSON File like this:

```
"member": [
    {
        "key": "1",
        "type": "bus_stop",         
        "name": "Western Avenue - SW-bound",
        "description": "Buckingham",
        "latitude": 52.00437,
        "longitude": -0.98989,
        "accuracy": 20,
        "atcocode": "040000004581",
        "distance": 846.0
    },
    {
        "key": "2",
        "type": "bus_stop",
        "name": "Overn Avenue - NE-bound",
        "description": "Buckingham",
        "latitude": 52.00378,
        "longitude": -0.98884,
        "accuracy": 20,
        "atcocode": "040000002388",
        "distance": 872.0
    }
]
```

What I want to do, it's to display with a marker the different places.
And when I click on marker, I've got all details in console

So What I'm doing :

```
export default class MapsScreen extends React.Component {
//Detail Screen to show from any Open detail button
state = { reports: [] }

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('***')  // call api for json
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({ reports: data.member })
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}

mapMarkers = () => {
    return this.state.reports.map((report) => <Marker
    key={report.key}
    title={report.name}
    coordinate={{ latitude: report.latitude, longitude: report.longitude }}
    title={report.name}
    description={report.description}
    onPress={this._onMarkerPress.bind(this, this.state.reports)}

    >
    </Marker >)
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapView
        style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: 52.0,
            longitude: -0.98,
            latitudeDelta: 10,
            longitudeDelta: 5
        }} >
        {this.mapMarkers()}
        
        </MapView>
        );
    }

    _onMarkerPress (markerData) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(markerData));
    }
}
```

The problem is when I click on first marker, I have all JSON and I want only the object of the first marker

Result:

```
[{"key":"1","type":"bus_stop","name":"Western Avenue - SW-bound","description":"Buckingham","latitude":52.00437,"longitude":-0.98989,"accuracy":20,"atcocode":"040000004581","distance":846},{"key":"2","type":"bus_stop","name":"Overn Avenue - NE-bound","description":"Buckingham","latitude":52.00378,"longitude":-0.98884,"accuracy":20,"atcocode":"040000002388","distance":872}]
```

Expected:

```
[{"key":"1","type":"bus_stop","name":"Western Avenue - SW-bound","description":"Buckingham","latitude":52.00437,"longitude":-0.98989,"accuracy":20,"atcocode":"040000004581","distance":846}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use filter method in onPress to filter your reports, before _onMarkerPress function receive the data:

```
onPress={this._onMarkerPress.bind(this, this.state.reports.filter(r => r.key === report.key ))}
```